# How can I strip <p> tags from entry content, but only if it's wrapped around a <figure>?

Tags: wygwam, content, strip-html

On occasion a `<figure>` tag will make it through WYGWAM with a `<p>` wrapped around it which breaks my layout (and is incorrect formatting anyway). Can I remove just the `<p>` tags that appear around specific elements? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the add-on Find and Replace Plus. http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/find-and-replace-plus

This should work for you.

```
{exp:replace_plus}
  {replace_area find="<p><figure>" replace="<figure>"}
  {replace_area find="</figure></p>" replace="</figure>"}
    text you want processed
  {/replace_area}
  {/replace_area}
{/exp:replace_plus}
```

Comment: So this *should* work but it's not recognizing the white space between `<p>` and `<figure>` tags. In the HTML there is often whitespace and newlines between those tags. Tried this but it didn't work: `{replace_area find="<p>:SPACE:<figure" replace="<figure"}`